# Drupal 8 hook_node_load not working

Tags: drupal-8

I am facing the following challenge for porting my module "Country Specific Nodes" to D8.
I need to finding the right replacement of Drupal 7's hook_node_load in Drupal 8. I tried `hook_entity_load` as well as `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load`, but it returns the Entity objects and not the actual node objects as in D7's `hook_node_load`.
Please let me know the right approach to this. Thanks for reading out and helping.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. Use >hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load($entities) for loading nodes. Actually this hook is not called every time a page loads. This is called only when the node is accessed or iterated.

Thanks.